# BibLaTeX - Number in bibliography the backreference link

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

The ASTM manual typesets its references so that the backreference in the bibliography is the label number in the bibliography.

The references are numbered with a red boldface number in parenthesis that when clicked on takes you to the location of the in-text citation in the paper.

I know how to make backreferences show up at the end of the reference.

Does anyone know how to turn my biblabel, which is a dark blue boldface number into the backreference. That is, I do not want the page number listed as the backreference link. I want the biblabel number as the link to the location where the reference was used in the paper. This is how the ASTM (American Society for Testing and Materials) manual does it.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,url=false,isbn=false,backref=true,style=science,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=100,block=none,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
backrefpage  = {see p.}, % for single page number
backrefpages = {see pp.} % for multiple page numbers
}

% code to make supercitations in brackets
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
\let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
\iffieldundef{prenote}
 {}
 {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
 \iffieldundef{postnote}
 {}
 {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
 [}%
 {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
 {}
 {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}]}

\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}%remove period at end of citation in bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}%make in-text citation number bold
\AtBeginBibliography{
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\color{blue!75!black}\mkbibbold{#1}}}% make bibliography label number bold and dark blue
%% The label number I want to be the backreference link instead of what I have now.

\DeclareFieldFormat{pagerefformat}{\color{blue!75!black}\{\mkbibbold{#1}\}}% I made braces around the backreference text: ''see p. 1'', bold, and dark blue 

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[pagerefformat]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}% this makes the backreference text ''see p. 1'' with the pagerefformat bold, dark blue


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
 }
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks,hyperfootnotes=false,plainpages=false]{hyperref} %
\hypersetup{
    citecolor={blue!75!black},% in-text citations dark blue
    linkcolor={blue!75!black},%the backreference is dark blue also
    colorlinks=true
 }

\begin{document}
We are citing \supercite{A01,C03} and \supercite{A01,C03,B02} and \cite{C03}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if a source is cited on multiple pages? Where should the link target?

Comment: I am just trying to replicate the ASTM manual. In the manual they do not cite that often and if they do it is only once per citation. I am wondering if it is possible to make either a hyperref or backreference as the biblabel number that is all...

Comment: But the same source may be cited on different pages e.g. page 2 and page 4. Where should the back reference target?

Comment: Target to the page where the reference was first cited. Let's pretend its not a citation/backreference but just a hyperref to some location. I want the biblabel/number to be a hyperref. This must be possible considering that the ASTM manual does this for every standard they have.

Comment: You can use `\printlist[pageref][1-1]{pageref}}` to get the first page reference.

Answer (score 2):

This links to the first page on which a particular citation occurs, it does not link to the exact place of the citation.

`biblatex` already creates a list of pages on which a reference was cited, we just need a way to extract the first page from that list in a fashion that allows us to pass the result to `\hyperlink`. In particular `\printlist[pageref][1-1]{pageref}` can't be used here, since it is robust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,url=false,isbn=false,backref=true,style=science,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=100,block=none,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage  = {see p\adddot},
  backrefpages = {see pp\adddot},
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {[%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
   }%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   ]}

\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[pagerefformat]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\makeatletter
\def\blxjk@grabfirslisttitem#1#2\@nil{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {\mkbibbold{#1\adddot}}
    {\edef\blxjk@firstpage{\expandafter\blxjk@grabfirslisttitem\abx@list@pageref{}\@nil}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\hyperlink{page.\blxjk@firstpage}{\mkbibbold{#1\adddot}}}
       {\mkbibbold{#1\adddot}}}}
\makeatletter


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks,hyperfootnotes=false,plainpages=false]{hyperref} %
\hypersetup{
    citecolor={blue!75!black},% in-text citations dark blue
    linkcolor={blue!75!black},%the backreference is dark blue also
    colorlinks=true
 }

\begin{document}
We are citing \supercite{sigfridsson} and \supercite{sigfridsson,worman} and \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography

\clearpage
We are citing \supercite{nussbaum,sigfridsson} and \supercite{nussbaum,sigfridsson} and \cite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
We are citing \supercite{sigfridsson} and \supercite{sigfridsson,worman} and \cite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image]